# Why is worship only possible in a sitting posture?

Tags: worship

Is it true that worship is only possible in a sitting posture?
 why we can't worship in sleeping posture?

Comment: Where did you get that idea?

Comment: @In Rajyoga,,,,

Comment: Well, for certain Yogic practices you may need to be sitting, but you don't need to sit just to pray.

Comment: @keshav ok, is it your own theory? or it has been written in any book.

Comment: I'm just not aware of any scriptures that say you're not allowed to pray while your body is in a particular posture.  But I can look for more information.

Comment: depends on what you mean by worship. If by worship you mean some kind of meditation then yes sitting is recommended as Swamiji has said. However if by worship you mean just praying to God. Then there are no rules, no regulations, no times, no stipulations, no postures nothing. All that is needed is Bhakti and Bhava or love for the Lord. All the best!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is scripture.

Brahma Sutras IV. I. 7-10. Verse 7 reads: "(One should meditate) in a sitting posture; because (in that way alone) meditation is possible."

Gita VI. 11-12. "Having established in a clean spot a firm seat...there sitting on that seat...he should practice yoga..."

Svetashvatara Upanishad II. 8. "Placing the body in a straight posture, with the chest, the throat, and the head held erect, making the organs enter the mind,..."

The mind will tend to sleep when done is a sleep position. If you try to do so standing, part of the mind must be kept aware of balance, full concentration is not possible. When done is a sitting position as described above, the mind is able to lose it's awareness of the body and the mind is able to concentrate all of its power internally.

Comment: “If you try to do so standing, part of the mind must be kept aware of balance, full concentration is not possible” <—— Agree but what about sages from the past who meditated long long years standing in tree position and such ? And sometimes in waist deep water of lake or river, or on mountain side in stormy weather. Maybe their concentrations skills much higher (?) Not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I agree sitting in lotus position is best for meditation. 
As sleeping or lying down pose renders sleep. 
Standing is a more hurried pose with poor 
concentration. 
Kneeling is a more namaz posture ,
If we see Hindu Temples & priests they normally use lotus position for prayers.

Comment: You should site some sources.